# Error en Java ´;` expected

Tags: java

Me da error en las dos líneas señaladas, pero no entiendo el por qué, ya que está escrito el punto y coma a final ;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece ser un problema que contiene errores tipográficos.

Comment: Por qué concatenas num1 con un `+` pero después concatenas otra cadena sin usar ningún operador?

Answer (score 3):

Créeme, cuando la máquina te dice que hay un error de sintaxis es que hay un error de sintaxis.

En este caso, te dice que espera un ';' y tú, como ves que al final de la línea tienes un ';' pues te quedas confundida.

El caso es que lo que tú ves como final de la línea, no es el final de la instrucción, ya que la instrucción la tienes rota porque no construyes bien la cadena al meter una variable en medio.

Fíjate que pones el '+' delante de la variable, pero no detrás.

Debería ser:

```
diferencia = "es anterior al actual. Han pasado " + num1 + " años.";
```

Y lo mismo con la otra línea.

Este tipo de errores deberías ser capaz de depurarlos tú misma, cuando los recibas, presta un poco más de atención sobre tu código, porque el IDE, y sobretodo el intérprete de Java, no se equivocan.